# assign np.na through series slicing

Tags: python, series

I have a series `mySeries` with `multiIndex (Date, Type)` like the following:

```
Date Type
2013  a     1
2013  b     2
2016  a     3
```

I would like to set all the rows with date 2013 to be `np.nan`.

I tried `mySeries['2013'] = np.nan`, it seems to work.

However, if i try the following, it does not work.

```
filter_date = ['2013']
mySeries[filter_date] = np.nan
```

It shows:

> KeyErorr: ['2013'] not in index.

May I know why? How to complete this through filter_date? I have to pass `filter_date`, as it is an output from other calculation, and it could be one value or could contain multiple dates which i need to filter out in mySeries.

Answer (score 0):

what about simply navigate through your filter?

```
filter_date = ['2013', '2016']
for f in filter_date:
    mySeries[f] = np.nan
```

maybe you can play with [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) function a little, bit loop is quick and simple solution for me in this case.